# Passing parameter while including PHP script

Tags: php, include

I want to do this, but it gives error :( for better understanding my problem I'm giving an example:

```
<?php
include 'script.php?text=hiii';
?>
```

content of the script.php

```
<?php
echo $_GET['text'];
?>
```

So, how can i pass an argument while including the script page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set `$_GET['text']` before including the file:

```
$_GET['text'] = 'hiii';
include 'script.php';
```

But this obviously won’t affect other variables like `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` etc.

Answer (score 3):

After you include any script, the included script will act as it's in the same page.

For  `yourpage.php?text=hiii`, that `include('script.php')` will automatically print `hiii`, as content of `script.php` will be in your included page.

Answer (score 1):

You could've done something like this:

```
<?php
$_GET['text'] = 'what you want to do';
include('script.php');
?>
```

Comment: thnx to both of you, thats really new to me :)

Comment: your welcome and welcome to stackoverflow. Be sure to read http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

Actually we don't need to add it to $_GET. just create a variable and use it. Example:

```
script.php
    <title><?php $text; ?></title>
    <!--- other code goes here -->
index.php
    <?php 
    $text = 'Welcome back';
    include 'script.php';
    ?>
```